# In an RPM %files section is it possible to specify a directory and all of its files and subdirectories recursively?

Tags: recursion, rpm, rpm-spec

I'm working on a packaging system that packages things in RPMs. I have a case where it would be very convenient to specify that I want a directory and every file and subdirectory under it included in the RPM. This of course, would be in the `%files` section.

Is there a way to do this? I notice that there is a way to specify that your list of files to include comes from a file. Would I have to run `find` in the `%install` section to generate that list into a file then use that file in the `%files` section later?

Comment: As far as I know you can use `X/*` patterns to mean, everything inside X

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is default behavior for rpm spec files:

```
%files
/directory
```

means: `/directory` and all files and directories below recursively.

**Note:** this only includes the files that you put in the `%{rpmbuildroot}`, not the files that are present on the system where you will install this rpm!

**another example**

```
%files
/usr/bin/*
```

make sure that some "official directories" like `/usr/bin` don't belong to your package (as `rpm` does not allow two packages to "own" the same file or directory). This line will package all files and folders you placed under `%{rpmbuildroot}/usr/bin/` recursively, but not `/usr/bin` itself.

Comment: So I should've tested before asking. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Is it considered standard practice to have RPMs who's only job is to create pieces of the top-level directory structure? Given the existence of the `filesystem` package on my Fedora machine, I would guess "Yes".

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case.

Comment: If your question is answered, consider accepting the answer.